# Regular expression - line doesn't begin with a string

Tags: regex

i've this text:

```
ASDSADSADSAD
THE BIG BLACK BOX 
4343
```

using a regular expression i need to match all rows that DON'T begin with "THE BIG"
I used this regular expression `^(?!(THE BIG))` ...but doesn't work (doesn't match anything)

On the other hand the opposite seems to work (begin with):  `^(THE BIG)`

any suggestion?!

look at the image below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nZQu.jpg

Comment: Do not use image links. What's your use case? Are you just trying to filter out lines that have that string? Or are you actually using regex to substitute something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!THE BIG).*
```

Your regex was OK, but you need to add the `.*` part to match the line without unwanted prefix.

Details:

- `^` beginning of the line
- `(?!THE BIG)` negative lookahead matching everything but `THE BIG
- `.*` rest of the line

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y84tYp/1)